# unity player chrome error making me crazy

Tags: google-chrome, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I want to open unity game in my chrome browser but it’s always showing me error that says **Unity web Player Needs Your Permission** and it’s not playing. I've installed unity player in my PC.
I have already tried all things but still it’s not working. 
I don't know how to solve this... help please!

Answer (score 3):

Enter `chrome://plugins/` into the URL bar for Chrome. Find the Unity Player Plugin and check the box for *Always Allowed*.

I imagine you just haven't allowed the plugin to run. When you try and run it, do you see an icon at the right end of the URL bar? If you do, that icon indicates a plugin was blocked. When you click on it, you should be able to decide what to do with it (allow or continue blocking).

You can find some more info [here](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/4354328?hl=en).